# What is the correct capitalization if "3D Printing"?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

How should "3D Printing be capitalized? Why?

A) 3D Printing

B) 3D printing

C) 3d Printing

D) 3d printing

Comment: "Printing" is only capitalized if the circumstances (title of a book, etc) demand it.  The "D" should probably always be capitalized, but it's a bit of a style issue.

Comment: What do you mean by a "style issue"? @HotLicks

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so I may mark this as answered?

Comment: I mean simply that there may be places (a magazine or a forum or whatever) where folks prefer the small "d".

Comment: I would note that the referenced question is not an *exact* duplicate, since Chase seemed more concerned about "printing" than about "3D".